# Bloquear tamaño de consola en C#

Tags: c#, consola

Necesito ajustar la ventana de la consola en un pequeño programa que he realizado pero con el metodo `Console.SetWindowSize(100, 200);` me salta una excepción que me dice que la consola tiene un tamaño máximo inferior a la que le estoy pidiendo...
¿Donde puedo cambiar esos maximos de ancho y alto?

Si consulto los atributos `Console.LargestWindowWidth` y `Console.WindowHeight` me devuelven unos valores de 240 y 30 respectivamente, pero no se como poder variarlos..

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según Microsoft, en la [documentación de `SetWindowSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException :
>
> - *width* o *height* es menor o igual que cero.
>
> O bien
>
> - *width* más *WindowLeft* o *height* más *WindowTop* es mayor o igual que *Int16.MaxValue*.
>
> -o-
>
> - *width* o *height* es mayor que el mayor ancho o la altura de ventana más grande posible para la resolución de pantalla y la fuente
>     de consola actuales.

También debes tener en cuenta que el tamaño no es en píxeles, **sino en filas/columnas**. Esto significa que dependiendo de la resolución de pantalla y de la fuente hay unos valores máximos. Por ejemplo,para 1600*1200 con la fuente standard `Consolas`, los valores máximos de ancho y largo son 200 columnas por 71 filas.

Resumiendo, **no puedes cambiar los valores máximos** ya que dependen como te digo de la resolución de pantalla, de la fuente utilizada etc.. y tampoco tendría mucho sentido ir mas allá, porque se acabaría con una ventana de consola que sobresaldría los límites de la pantalla. En tu caso, si quieres ir al máximo posible, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);
```